# Have I done something wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am a irregular and inexperienced programmer. I've clearly fallen foul of how I am supposed to ask a question as [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29992940/how-can-i-get-octave-to-change-the-variables-in-my-input-files) is getting voted down but I have absolutely no idea why. I assume I'm falling foul of some community rules or guidelines but don't understand why. I really need help with the question I'm trying to ask because I'm just not that good at programming.

So if someone could help me out and tell me what's going on, how I can improve my question and avoid problems like this in the future that would be great. (If someone can answer it even better.)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong about it - but then again, I am not that familiar with sed or octave.

Comment: @Oded: also not familiar with them (I knew a different "sed" ages ago, but won't tar this one with the same brush); but it doesn't seem very much like a "programming" question.

Comment: I also don't know octave, so take this with a grain of salt… I don't see anything in this question I would downvote, but I do thing it could be improved. This isn't a very good MCVE, because it doesn't include input and expected output. Also, if octave gives you any kind of "traceback" information to let you know which part of this expression the error came from, that would be useful. Also, your indentation is jagged, the "same string" isn't actually the same (I know enough sed to understand that your `/` to `~` change shouldn't affect anything, but would most octave users?).

Comment: Also, you've tagged this "terminal", but it has nothing to do with the terminal. It has a little to do with the _shell_ (which is also the thing you're inputting stuff into in the second half), but those aren't the same. You've also tagged it "system", but that tag isn't for the `system` function.

Comment: Right thanks, I will edit the tags. So what should I be using the terminal tag for? Just for future reference.

Comment: meta effect .. this question is now upvoted.

Comment: @trooper It's now my most upvoted question on stackoverflow. Not that I am complaining but it seems odd.

Comment: Tags can be clicked to show a short summary plus questions tagged as such, and in that screen click "Learn more" to see some more, including (usually) further links. You can even click the link while you are still entering the tag!

Comment: I think I'm gonna just start posting meta discussions about all my questions to tripple my rep in a 24 hour span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This is not a question I would have downvoted, but I'm also not familiar with Octave and sed.*

Thanks to [the "meta effect"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/159034), your question now is +7 *(-4/+11)* and one of the glaring issues has been fixed: your tags.

---

You started off with [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) and [octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octave), which both appear to be directly related to your question. This is good, as tags *should be directly related* to your question.

Later on you added three additional tags: [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal), [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system), and [eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eval). While your question does include the `system` function, that's not what [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) is for. If you click through on [system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/system) you will see the excerpt says

> System may refer to a set of interdependent components; Low level infrastructure like the operating system (from a high language point of view) or an object or function for accessing the previous

Which *isn't quite* what you are looking for, and having bad tags will attract the wrong developers which will give you a downvote. Every time.

The other tag you added was [terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/terminal) which you mentioned in your question that you *were using*, but your question *didn't really involve it*. I think [@abarnert](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/908494/abarnert) hit the nail on the head [in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/292136/have-i-done-something-wrong-with-this-question?cb=1#comment185710_292136) as to why you shouldn't use that tag here. Using the tag [shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell) here also carried the same issues.

---

[Last I checked](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29992940/6), the tags had been cleaned up back to the original two that were there: [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) and [octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octave)

As I'm not familiar enough with [sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sed) and [octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/octave) to judge the quality of the question itself, I can't comment on why else it would have attracted downvotes.

Answer (score -10):

I had the same thing happen to me, because I wasn't familiar enough with the language I was asking about. They said something along the lines of:

> Go learn that language first as you dont know it. -1

Comment: People often feel that way on SO, as [it's billed as](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) _"a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"_.  Sometimes the way questions are written, it seems to people reading that perhaps the questioner isn't up to this "standard", and SO really isn't the place to provide long winded tutorials.

Comment: that is truth, but this kind is when user asks to walk him through the thing and not answer question

Comment: _"and some of them are haters"_ - I don't agree with that.  Personally, I feel that there are a _lot_ of questions of Stack Overflow, so I may come across as short sometimes, but that's because I dip in when I can and provide help where I can.  If questions are badly written or badly researched, chances are they will attract short, quick comments rather than the help the OP wants, but only because it comes across in their post that they haven't tried to help themselves first.

Comment: _"they haven't tried to help themselves first."_ well, i have on most of my questions and i didn't find any relevant answers to them, so i asked a question on stackoverflow, but instead of somebody just helping me get the answer, they just down vote

Comment: Looking at your first question (php sessions), there are two main points that spring to mind.  Firstly, the question just says "it doesn't work" - _how_ doesn't it work?  What were you expecting to happen, and what did/didn't happen?  That's one reason why it may have been downvoted.  The second being that there is a ton of information out there on PHP sessions already.  Final point on this - you had a comment from someone who I recognize as a fairly regular user within a minute of you posting the question that had the answer, so I wouldn't call that not helping.

Comment: that question is exclusion and im not talking about this account

Comment: I edited the answer, it may confuse readers of the comments a bit.

Comment: _"I edited the answer"_ thanks.